# X11 freezes instantly with Shift-3

Tags: x11, gnome, keyboard

On Arch Linux running GNOME, if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>,
it locks X (nothing but the mouse cursor works). 
All window updates are suspended. 
The only option is to zap it
with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

I've looked in logs, nothing.
I've searched the web, nothing.
I've tried every possible keypress, nothing.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> works just fine,
as does <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

I'm on a Mac Pro, with a UK Apple keyboard. I don't think this should matter, but it is the `£` (pound) symbol that comes out on the console before I run `startx`. In X, I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and get a pound without any problems. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> gives me `#` as expected.

Any ideas where to start with this? Is there extra logging I can somehow enable?

---

`xmodmap -pke` gives:

`keycode  12 = 3 sterling 3 sterling numbersign sterling threesuperior sterling 3 sterling threesuperior sterling`

---

`xev` output. I pushed <kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>. Interestingly, it continued writing to the output after the DM froze.

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 338011, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x10, keycode 53 (keysym 0x78, x), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 338091, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x10, keycode 53 (keysym 0x78, x), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 339867, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x10, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 340219, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x11, keycode 12 (keysym 0xa3, sterling), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a3) "£"
XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a3) "£"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 340299, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x11, keycode 12 (keysym 0xa3, sterling), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a3) "£"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 340411, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x11, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 349763, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x10, keycode 10 (keysym 0x31, 1), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x4a3, subw 0x0, time 349835, (655,-7), root:(840,525),
state 0x10, keycode 10 (keysym 0x31, 1), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Interesting. Does the system lock up hard, or you can e.g. still `ssh` into it from another computer and `kill` the X server, or X applications? Can you catch the shift-3 event with `xev`, or does it freeze before you see the result? Anything unusual on the '3' key (keycode 12, if the Mac keyboard is similar to PC keyboard) if you do `xmodmap -pke`?

Comment: it's a soft lock - ctrl-alt-backspace quits X, and the mouse still works, but the clock freezes along with all other window updates. I presume SSH still works. I'll try `xev` and `xmodmap` - thanks!

Comment: I just tried starting `gdm` first, and it works without issue. The thing is I use the console a lot, I go into X about 40% of the time.

Comment: So it's only an issue of you use `startx` directly, not with `gdm`? What window manager is run with `startx`? The sterling symbol is different than other keys in that it consists of two UTF-8 bytes, are any applications (including the window manager) running that could possibly choke on that? Can you try to `ssh` in after a freeze, and start killing X applications until you narrow it down to possible culprits? What happens you try to replace the sterling symbol with something else using `xmodmap` (see manpage how to do that)?

Comment: Yep, only with startx, and it fires Gnome via `dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session` in .xinitrc (otherwise Gnome Terminal doesn't work). More or less zero running other than Gnome itself. I'll try hacking around with `xmodmap`, and I might even try `xfce` or removing the dbus launcher to see what that does. I'm on Arch so it's a rolling latest-version of everything... Thanks for the tips, I'll feedback when I have tried these ideas. Good point about 2-byte chars; maybe I need to install support somewhere for unicode.

Comment: Do you have this problem with any other key, in particular `¬`? Do you have this problem if you change to another keyboard layout (e.g. try a French keyboard layout and press Shift + the key that is `]` in a UK/US layout to insert `£`)?

Comment: Changing to French keyboard solves this for the 'Sterling' symbol, but it seems that other unicode chars still cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `dbus-launch --exit-with-session` from `.xinitrc` appears to resolve this, for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 0):

very interesting.. I am running today - 5 years after orig post - in a very similar pattern.

I am running Manjaro (based on Arch Linux) since several months now and had  rolling updates applied as they came in.
Since a few days (weeks ?) i had irregular hangs on X11 as described above. For me this appears under the following conditions:

- .xinitrc calls the "get_session" to get the dbus-launched
- i enter the key with the German letter 'ß' w/o modifer-keys like Shift. (e.g. typing '?' which is on the same key, it is not freezing)

Things I have tried to narrow down:

- new user (with no configs) - no influence
- using icewm instead of plasma - no influence
- commenting out the dbus-launching - fixes the problem
- changing keymap to US - no influence

As this was working fluently a few weeks ago, i assume some software broke?any idea where to look at?

@antonyh Did you ever find out the reason?

Comment: Sadly no, I never figured this one out.